# How to hide/show inside a repeater?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to hide/show a `div` on anchor click, but that doesn't work.

I have repeater, and in it there are so many posts. There are bound images, descriptions and comments (anchor tag).

When I click on a comment, the associated `div` will be displayed.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#<%= divSearch.ClientID%>').toggle('medium');return false;">Show Search</a>
<div class="widget-content" id="divSearch" runat="server" style="display: none; background-color: #EEEEEE;">Content goes here</div>
```

It works perfectly outside of repeater item template, but when I placed it inside the repeater, then it doesn't work

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: When i placed inside itemtemplate it shows that "div search dose not exits in current content". I know that it id related error but enable to solved it

Comment: If you provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue described, it will be easier to help.

Comment: i am also tried that but in snippet it shows that jquery version not supported.

Comment: If any one have comment example like facebook then suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other 2 answers given are forgetting that there are more that one `divSearch` in a Repeater, so you cannot directly access them in the aspx. For that you need to use FindControl, this can be done inline. You have to find the Panel inside the Container and get that ClientID.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="divSearch" runat="server" style="display:none">
            <%# Eval("value") %>
        </asp:Panel>

        <a href="#" onclick="$('#<%# Container.FindControl("divSearch").ClientID %>').toggle('medium');return false;">Show</a>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...!! problem is solved using this.

Comment: Hello..@VDWWD in divSearch I placed one textbox and button for  post a comment for that which event and how to use that?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the ItemCommand event: https://forums.asp.net/t/1273966.aspx?FindControl+in+repeater+ItemCommand

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to implement this is in the `ItemDataBound` event.

Markup

```
<a href="#" runat="server" id="showSearch">Show Search</a>
<div class="widget-content" id="divSearch" runat="server" style="display: none; background-color: #EEEEEE;">Content goes here</div>
```

Event

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var link = e.Item.FindControl("showSearch") as HtmlControl;
        link.Attributes["onclick"] = $"$('{e.Item.FindControl("divSearch").ClientID}').toggle('medium'); return false;";
    }
}
```

Comment: How about now @LoveAajkal?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the template control, you need to use `<%#` instead of `<%=`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#<%#Container.FindControl("divSearch").ClientID%>').toggle('medium');return false;">Show Search</a>
```

Comment: Yes, like VDWWD said, I forgot to search in the `Container`. However, you don't need to convert your `div` into a panel like he said. It will work with the `div`. See my updated answer. But the panel will be rendered as a `div`, so they end up to be the same thing.